# Finding a function to express perfect square in terms of 1 and other numbers in terms of zero

Tags: functions

What function f(x) is equal to 1 only when x is a perfect square otherwise f(x)=0?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I need any function f(x) where x is a real number. When x is a perfect square the value of the function f(x) is 1. For other values of x the value of the function f(x) is 0. I need to find out a function satisfying above properties.

Comment: I mean... you just defined one. "Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ is a perfect square; otherwise $f(x)=0$", boom there you go. It's a perfectly valid definition.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I want to define the required f(x) in terms of standard functions like say sine, cosine and so on. Not in terms of SET LANGUAGE.

Comment: @JohnyRoyan All non-negative real numbers are perfect squares.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called $\tau$ (read as "tau") where $\tau: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ sends $n \mapsto \#\{\text{factors of } n\}$.

For example, $\tau(10) = 4$ because $10$ has four factors: $1, 2, 5, 10$.

Any non-square has an even number of factors and any perfect square has an odd number of factors.

Therefore, the function $f(n) := \tau(n) \mod 2$ will suffice for your purpose.

You can test it out on some cases in WolframAlpha, e.g., [**35**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=tau%2835%29+mod+2) yields $0$; [**36**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=tau%2836%29+mod+2) yields one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

$$\mathbb{1}_A(x) :=\begin{cases}1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \notin A.  \end{cases}$$

We let $A$ be $\{x: \sqrt{x}\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$

Hence $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{\{x:\sqrt{x} \in \mathbb{Z}\}}$.